# Is it possible this unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, scene

I hope this question is fine here, I kindly would like to know if what I'm thinking is possible in Unity before to get start digging to it. I'm not familiar with unity I always use SpriteKit and Scenekit from apple.

Im currently working on an app which display a 3d cockpit of an airplane with all his instruments. In order to create the instruments displays I used a sprite scene apply as a texture of a screen object to simulate the screen.
So like this I'm able to simulate and display the indication that should appear on screen
See picture:

[image: pic]

[image: pic 2]

My question is: Is it possibile to replicate something like this in unity? How do you create instrument inside cockpit? What should I look into? Is the same concept of using sprite element as texture in order to be able simulate instruments?

What should I look into..

Comment: Are those instruments supposed to be interacted with?
You can use a Canvas with World Coordinates to display your instruments

Comment: I mean all instruments behind have all their logic to simulate the entire aircraft system.. it mean need to be able to display all type of data like temperature sped , I need to have some needle to display engine data.. basically all the data that an airplane instrument have to display.

Comment: You can do it. Is it a lot of work. Yes. But the facia can be a sprite with other things behind it.

Comment: Agree. you can do it, you can either use World Canvas or you can also use Raycasting.,